# Duplicate multiple records with one INSERT statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sql-insert

In MS-Access 2019, I'd like to **duplicate existing records** from `tblTest` and change one field `tLink` as a foreign key to another table.

I know how to do it with `VBA` looping over recordsets, but I'd like to use `SQL` here.
I assume it can be solved with a **single statement**, and as SQL-newbie I'm eager to learn how to do it.

So let's assume a simple table `tblTest`, `tID` is `Primary Key` and `auto-number`

```
tID    tLink    tName
Long   Long     Text(50)
-----------------------------
1       3       Bill
2      17       Sue
3       9       Tom
4       3       Chris
```

I'd like to duplicate all records with `tLink = 3` and set their `tLink` to `1`.

When snooping around in various tutorials, I learned ...

```
INSERT INTO tblTest SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE tID=1
```

... but this fails because of `tID` having to be a unique value.

So I am stuck at this point, and removing the `primary key` from the table is not an option here. Is there a way around it?

So, (1) how to duplicate one record without running into the `primary key` issue, and then, (2) multiple records with 1 `SQL` statement?

I would then use `UPDATE` to set `tLink` to `1` `WHERE tLink=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to duplicate all records with `tLink = 3` and set their `tLink` to `1`.

If you have an auto-number column, then you can just leave it apart in the insert statement. Access will automatically assign a new value for every inserted row.

What you want should be as simple as:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest(tLink, tName) SELECT 1, tName FROM tblTest WHERE tLink = 3
```